# What compressive strength is exceeded by $95\%$ of the samples?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The compressive strength of samples of cement can be modeled by a normal distribution with a mean of $6000$ kilograms per square centimeter and a standard deviation of $100$ kilograms per square centimeter.
What strength is exceeded by $95\%$ of the samples?
Answer: $5835 kg/cm^2$

This is the question 4.47 from (Douglas Montgomery's "Applied Statistics and Probability for Engineers", 3nd ed.)

What I tried so far:

$$P(Z>z) = 0.95\\
1 - P(Z \le z) = 0.95\\
\Phi (z) = 0.05$$

But I am not sure how to go on, or if I'm heading in the right direction.

Comment: Your attempts are sensible. Where are you getting stuck? Do you have a textbook that covers this topic?

Comment: You need to use the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution with mean 6000 and standard deviation 100 to find at what x you have the cdf =0.05. You are heading in the right direction but probably have some work to do.